# ,Awesomium Requirements on Clients

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, awesomium

I used Awesomium web browser in a project, and everything works just fine in "developer" PCs(I tested its functionality on several PCs),
but on a raw client (with no visual studio or other third party software installed), the embedded browser won't even open.
Is there any requirements to be applied on the clients in order to use Awesomium?
And if yes, What are they?
(for example, should I make IE default browser or Update ActiveX,etc...?)
Thanks for your time.

3 Days Later :

OK,now I know what is causing the problem,
all it needed was to "run program on admin for once", and after that,
even for simple users, program was working fine.
I assume Awesomium will create some folder(like temp,cache or something) at FIRST use,
after that, there won't be a problem,
but still,
"What file(s) or folder(s) it is trying to create?"

Comment: Can you list the files you deploy to your app's bin/program files folder?

Answer (score 0):

http://wiki.awesomium.net/getting-started/redist.html

You need to distribute all Awesomium dependencies with your application. Just set `Copy Local` to `True` on Awesomium.Core and Awesomium.Windows.Controls for WPF control or Awesomium.Windows.Forms for WinForms control in your project References and all required files should be copied to the build output folder.

You can also install them into GAC on client PCs, could be useful if you have several projects with Awesomium.

Answer (score 0):

Well,in the end,I had to run the program as **Adminisrator** for the first time on **each computer**, after the first time, you can use software as User.